# MySQL query to fetch this data in Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm not very good with MySQL queries, I'm looking to fetch the columns from multiple data using MySQL query. Considering DB name is "db_name" and prefix is like "wp_",

```
post_name
post_title
post_content
featured image url
categories
tag
```

Can I fetch this stuff in a single query or I have to use multiple queries? The categories and tags are the ones that would be associated with a given post. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You want column names or data from inside column `categories` and `tags`?

Comment: the data inside them

Comment: I assume you know basic MySQL query, I mean at least you know `SELECT column_name1, column_name2 FROM table` right? The next part would be adding `WHERE` condition(s). So something like `SELECT column_name1, column_name2 FROM table WHERE column_name1=condition1 AND column_name2=condition2`